# Hang on close when using touchtarget

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I am working on an application for the Microsoft Surface 2.0, using C#, XNA, and the Surface.Core libraries. When I instantiate the TouchTarget and then immediately dispose of it.

```
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        TouchTarget touchTarget = new TouchTarget(this.Window.Handle);
        touchTarget.Dispose();
        touchTarget = null;
        base.Initialize();
    }
```

When I exit the Visual Studio 2010 Debugger it hangs ~3-5 seconds. The hang happens after the code has exited out of the using part of the Main method.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (mainGame game = new mainGame())
        {
            game.Run();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this happen with a release build on the emulator?

Comment: It still hangs if I have the Input Simulator running regardless of if I have the Debug builder or the Release builder selected.